# Knowing which OR statement failed when many Or statements are involved?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have two tables: `OldSales` and `NewSales`. The `NewSales` will be the *revised* version. Both tables should match, so I have to find differences in rows.

Both have 13 columns: `EmpId`, and the 12 months of the year (ie. `EmpId`, `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar`,..., `Dec`)

I need to check that the sales for each month match within the two tables, so my sql looks like below.

```
SELECT
OldSales.EmpId, 
OldSales.Jan, NewSales.Jan, 
OldSales.Feb, NewSales.Feb,
/* Here goes Mar through Nov */
OldSales.Dec, NewSales.Dec
from
OldSales inner join NewSales on
OldSales.EmpId = NewSales.EmpId
where 
OldSales.Jan <> NewSales.Jan or
OldSales.Feb <> NewSales.Feb or
/* Here goes the OR clause for Mar through Nov */
OldSales.Dec <> NewSales.Dec
```

If rows are returned, I scroll through the results to see where I see differences between columns. The actual table has many more columns, so it's a pain scrolling through the values to find inconsistencies.

Question: is it possible to add something to the SQL so that I know that, for example, `Feb` and `Apr` don't match in the first row, `Dec` doesn't match in the 2nd row, etc?

Comment: Add a `CASE` expression? Though, what would you expect if multiple columns are different? Perhaps *multiple* `CASE` expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You could normalize your data and just compare individual months.

Something like

```
SELECT OldSales.EmpId, A.MonthName, A.OldSalesAmount, A.NewSalesAmount
from OldSales
inner join NewSales
    on OldSales.EmpId = NewSales.EmpId
cross apply (
    values
        (1, 'Jan', OldSales.Jan, NewSales.Jan),
        (2, 'Feb', OldSales.Feb, NewSales.Feb),
        ...
        (12, 'Dec', OldSales.Dec, NewSales.Dec)
) A(MonthNum, MonthName, OldSalesAmount, NewSalesAmount)
where A.OldSalesAmount <> A.NewSalesAmount
order by OldSales.EmpId, A.MonthNum
```

Sample results:

| EmpId | MonthName | OldSalesAmount | NewSalesAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | 1100.00 | 1111.00 |
| 2 | Feb | 2200.00 | 2222.00 |
| 2 | Dec | 2300.00 | 2333.00 |
| 4 | Jan | 4100.00 | 4111.00 |
| 4 | Feb | 4200.00 | 4222.00 |
| 4 | Dec | 4300.00 | 4333.00 |

As a variation of the above, you could perform the compare within the `CROSS APPLY` and use `STRING_AGG()` to gather the results into a month list. The outer query could then check for an empty month list.

```
SELECT OldSales.EmpId, A.DiffMonths,
    OldSales.Jan, NewSales.Jan, 
    OldSales.Feb, NewSales.Feb,
    /* Here goes Mar through Nov */
    OldSales.Dec, NewSales.Dec
from OldSales
inner join NewSales
    on OldSales.EmpId = NewSales.EmpId
cross apply (
    select STRING_AGG(A.MonthName, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY A.MonthNum) AS DiffMonths
    from (
            values
            (1, 'Jan', OldSales.Jan, NewSales.Jan),
            (2, 'Feb', OldSales.Feb, NewSales.Feb),
            ...
            (12, 'Dec', OldSales.Dec, NewSales.Dec)
    ) A(MonthNum, MonthName, OldSalesAmount, NewSalesAmount)
    where A.OldSalesAmount <> A.NewSalesAmount
) A
where DiffMonths is not null
order by OldSales.EmpId
```

Sample results:

| EmpId | DiffMonths | Jan | Jan | Feb | Feb | Dec | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | 1100.00 | 1111.00 | 1200.00 | 1200.00 | 1300.00 | 1300.00 |
| 2 | Feb, Dec | 2100.00 | 2100.00 | 2200.00 | 2222.00 | 2300.00 | 2333.00 |
| 4 | Jan, Feb, Dec | 4100.00 | 4111.00 | 4200.00 | 4222.00 | 4300.00 | 4333.00 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hucadD3l) for a demo.